# using the condition if in a function

Tags: mysql

I created a function using "if..else if", in order to cover a field and extract some characters and store them in a column:

```
delimiter |
CREATE FUNCTION METTRE (s VARCHAR(2000)) RETURNS VARCHAR(10000)
DETERMINISTIC
   BEGIN

           DECLARE str  VARCHAR(2000);
           DECLARE str1  VARCHAR(2000);
            DECLARE str2  VARCHAR(2000);
            DECLARE str3  VARCHAR(2000);
           DECLARE toFind  VARCHAR(2000);
           DECLARE co VARCHAR(2000);
           SET co='';
           SET str='';
           SET str1='';
           SET str2='';
SET str1 =substring(trim(substring_index(s,'du',-1)),1,3);
 SET str2 =substring(trim(substring_index(s,':',-1)),1,3);
 SET str =substring(trim(substring_index(s,'sur',-1)),1,3);
IF  (str in ('ZAG','TUN','TOZ','TAT','SOS','SIL','SFX','SBO','RNC','BAR','BEJ','BIZ','BSC','GAB','GAF','JEN','KAI','KAS','KEB','KEF','MAH','MED','MON','NAB')) =1 THEN set co = str ;
ELSE IF ((str not in ('ZAG','TUN','TOZ','TAT','SOS','SIL','SFX','SBO','RNC','BAR','BEJ','BIZ','BSC','GAB','GAF','JEN','KAI','KAS','KEB','KEF','MAH','MED','MON','NAB')) and (str1 in ('ZAG','TUN','TOZ','TAT','SOS','SIL','SFX','SBO','RNC','BAR','BEJ','BIZ','BSC','GAB','GAF','JEN','KAI','KAS','KEB','KEF','MAH','MED','MON','NAB')))=1 THEN set co = str1 ;
ELSE IF ((str1 not in ('ZAG','TUN','TOZ','TAT','SOS','SIL','SFX','SBO','RNC','BAR','BEJ','BIZ','BSC','GAB','GAF','JEN','KAI','KAS','KEB','KEF','MAH','MED','MON','NAB'))and (str2 in ('ZAG','TUN','TOZ','TAT','SOS','SIL','SFX','SBO','RNC','BAR','BEJ','BIZ','BSC','GAB','GAF','JEN','KAI','KAS','KEB','KEF','MAH','MED','MON','NAB')))=1 THEN SET co = str2 ;
ELSE set co = '1' ; 

END IF;
END IF;
END IF;


           return co;
   END |
delimiter;
```

But it's not working only the first condition is used.

```
IF  (str in ('ZAG','TUN','TOZ','TAT','SOS','SIL','SFX','SBO','RNC','BAR','BEJ','BIZ','BSC','GAB','GAF','JEN','KAI','KAS','KEB','KEF','MAH','MED','MON','NAB')) =1 THEN set co = str ;
```

Comment: I guess the `IF` is used because the condition is met? It's kind of hard to tell without any example input.

Comment: I have a field for example (Bonjour,
on note un Pb Fail et Drop TBF Sporadique sur quelques cellules Nokia depuis le 25/01/2015:
TUN3156S2 (Regression de tous les KPI CS et PS)
SFX1239S3
Merci de voir.
Cdt,) i would like to take the three characters after'sur' .If there is not , i takes the after 'du' and after the ':'

Comment: I don't think you need that `=1` bit at the end of your condition. I'm not MySQL expert, but it seems like `str1 in (<list>)` should return TRUE or FALSE on it's own. It could be that the return from that function is always '1' so the first condition with the `=1` bit is always true.

Comment: i think it's not that problem?

Comment: @JNevill MySQL returns `1` for `IN`, if the condition is true, and `0` if it's not true (ie `SELECT 2 IN (0,3,5,7)` returns 0).

Comment: i don't undrestand.'1' is just a number to select the unuseful field.i need please some information to resolve the problem of 'else if' .

Comment: Why don't you do as @waka suggested and give us some example input. What is a value of your incoming variable `s` for this stored procedure. It's really hard to guess what your program is doing without knowing what you are feeding into it.

Comment: @waka Generally I use CASE statements where `CASE str1 IN (<list>) THEN...` works as expected. It seems odd that MySQL needs to wrap a function that returns 1 or 0 into a second formula to change those boolean returns into True or False. It wouldn't surprise me though that MySQL requires this in a stored procedure since it's sort of an oddball RDBMS.